# select on socket slow in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have a weird problem with select taking unexpected long on a socket in Linux.

- The server is receiving data all the time, receive socket buffer size is 65536.
- a client sending data all the time, send socket buffer size is 4096.

In general the data transfer is really fast. But: a select in the client to test if a write will not block takes really long (sending data without calling select before: 0.5s, sending same data with calling select before actual sending the data: 5s). The problem is specific to the buffer sizes. If I increase the send buffer in the client to let's say 4*4096 the problem goes away.

Now I want to know why the select takes so long with the specific buffer sizes. Example code is here: http://pastebin.com/PqisLnLU

Same code runs on Windows and even Windows Subsystem for Linux without these weird behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: "a select in the client to test if a write will not block takes really long (without select: 0.5s, with select 5s)" - how can you have a select without a select...?

Comment: Thanks, fixed in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the effect of [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm), which is used to improve TCP throughput at the cost of latency.

The writes are relatively small and are being delayed in case more data is written in the near future, which could then be bundled together in a single IP packet. When you use `select` before sending, you are not sending more (because the send buffer is still full) and so there is a significant delay before the packet is sent (and the buffer is emptied). When instead you do not use `select` the buffer is full and so it is shunted through the network stack immediately as you `send` more.

(I'm guessing you're running your client and server programs on the same machine, so the "network" connection between them is actually the loopback interface, which has a quite high MTU; otherwise, Nagle's algorithm probably would not be an issue here).

When you increase the buffer size sufficiently, a suitable IP packet size is reached at some point during filling of the buffer, and the data is pushed through the network immediately (and cleared from the send buffer when receipt is acknowledged) - so there is no delay.

Try disabling Nagle's algorithm (in the client):

```
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

...

value = 1;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char*)&value, sizeof(int)))
{
    printf("\n Error : SetSockOpt TCP_NODELAY Failed \n");
}
```

You will see that the variant using `select` is then just as fast as the variant with no `select` operation.

Comment: Yes, that fixes that issue, thanks for pointing this out! But why is select so much faster on Windows (I guess this is hard to answer as we both do not have the source of Windows)? On both systems TCP_NODELAY is 0.

Comment: @RobertK right, I don't really know; it's a different TCP/IP implementation. It's possible that Windows pushes out a packet as soon as the send buffer is full, which is quite reasonable behaviour.

Comment: @RobertK I should add that linux actually sets a buffer size that is double the requested size. If you set the buffer size to 2048 (which is then doubled) you get the interesting behaviour that using `select` or not is always (equally) slow. In this case I believe it's because the send buffer can only be cleared when the acknowledgement packet is received from the peer; you are forcing a round-trip delay into each packet.

Comment: Maybe the answer is in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214397 "If the stack has coalesced a data buffer larger than the Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU), a full-sized packet is sent immediately without waiting for the ACK from the remote host. On an Ethernet network, the MTU for TCP/IP is 1460 bytes."

Comment: @RobertK indeed, though that quote is essentially just a description of part of Nagle's algorithm. Perhaps the key is that when I run the programs on linux, I do so on the same host, so the packets go via the loopback interface (`lo`)  which according to `ifconfig` has an MTU of 65536. On Windows maybe it is treated the same as ethernet instead, or at least has a similarly small MTU. If you've not done so you might want to try and run the client and server programs on different hosts.

Comment: Great finding! When I change the MTU of loopback on Linux to 1460bytes the difference disappears, too. I do not understand completely the influence of the MTU here. Is it so that the send buffer is full but because the MTU value is not reached the data is not send out?

Comment: @RobertK "Is it so that the send buffer is full but because the MTU value is not reached the data is not send out?" - yes, if the buffered data does not exceed MTU size then it will be delayed by Nagle's algorithm. Check the Wikipedia link for the algorithm I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know why the select takes so long with the specific buffer sizes

Because the client's send buffer is too small. 4096 bytes is less than the default on any OS I am aware of. The default on Linux was somewhere around 52k more than ten years ago. You can't possibly 'fill the pipe' unless your sender's socket send buffer is comparable to the receiver's socket receive buffer in size.

I would also question why you are using non-blocking I/O and `select()` in the client at all. Unless you are connecting to multiple servers there is really no point. Just use a dedicated thread and let it block.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (which is *why* does it take so long?)

Comment: "You can't possibly 'fill the pipe' unless your sender's socket send buffer is comparable to the receiver's socket receive buffer in size" I don't know what misconception would lead you to suggest that this is the case.